# Python Pandas Copied Columns not Appearing in Head

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add two new columns to my DataFrame that are copy of current columns, but despite seeing outputs of my `assign` method showing the columns as a part of my DataFrame, when I run the `head()` method they do not appear. Am I using the correct command to update my DataFrame with duplicates of two columns under new names? I am running all of these commands through jupyter notebooks

```
Current Column -> New Column (Duplicate of Current Column)
'date' -> 'ts'
'y' -> 'clicks'
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fbprophet import Prophet

df = pd.read_csv('car-sales-raw-data.csv')

allDf = df
allDf = allDf.fillna(0)
allDf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(allDf['date'])

allDf.head()
""" OUTPUT """
        date        day_of_week leads clicks  cars
    181 2017-07-01  Saturday    44    611     26
    182 2017-07-02  Sunday      30    203     14
    183 2017-07-05  Wednesday   55    994     25
    184 2017-07-06  Thursday    50    2854    23
    185 2017-07-07  Friday      78    850     52

# duplicate date and click columns

allDf.assign(ds = allDf['date'])
allDf.assign(y = allDf['clicks'])
allDf.head()

""" OUTPUT """
            date        day_of_week leads clicks  cars
        181 2017-07-01  Saturday    44    611     26
        182 2017-07-02  Sunday      30    203     14
        183 2017-07-05  Wednesday   55    994     25
        184 2017-07-06  Thursday    50    2854    23
        185 2017-07-07  Friday      78    850     52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually assign the columns to your dataframe but you don't store the updated dataframe. To do so use the following lines of code

```
allDf

         date      day_of_week  leads   clicks  cars
181     2017-07-01  Saturday    44      611     26
182     2017-07-02  Sunday      30      203     14
183     2017-07-05  Wednesday   55      994     25
184     2017-07-06  Thursday    50      2854    23
185     2017-07-07  Friday      78      850     52

allDf = allDf.assign(ds = allDf['date'])

allDf

           date     day_of_week     leads   clicks  cars    ds
181     2017-07-01  Saturday        44      611     26  2017-07-01
182     2017-07-02  Sunday          30      203     14  2017-07-02
183     2017-07-05  Wednesday       55      994     25  2017-07-05
184     2017-07-06  Thursday        50      2854    23  2017-07-06
185     2017-07-07  Friday          78      850     52  2017-07-07
```

Comment: simple enough fix. I didn't realize that the method acts as a temporary fix and not persistent. Thanks!